# Magento 2 getProductCollection Interceptor everytime

Tags: magento2, interceptor

I would like to intercept and modify a product collection every time it is used.  However, I am having issues figuring out what functions to create a plugin for.   I mostly understand Interceptors, just need a pointer.

I tried with the categoy model but it didnt seem to work at all.

In di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Myextension_Something_Plugin_Category" sortOrder="0" type="MyExtension\Something\Plugin\Category" />
</type>
```

The function

```
public function afterGetProductCollection(AbstractDb $collection)
{
    var_dump($collection);
    return $collection;
}
```

EDIT:   It seems I can intercept other things like search but it will not intercept category.. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work on \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Comment: I am the author of the post...  I just changed the model to \Magento\Framework\DataObject instead of Magento\Catalog\Model\Category  .....